# multiprocessing in python causing issues of broken data

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I am running my python code in threads using multiprocessing module to write my input data(~2 source files) into a single target file.

However while I am writing, some of the records are getting broken in the target file(400 records out of 100k records got broken)

By broken record i mean, output record was expected as:

"column1","column2","column3","column4","column4"

However it was broken as:

mn3","column4","column4"

Can some please help, is there a lock multiple processes are creating on my target file? and how can i avoid this situation? Or is there any alternate solution to this

```
def process_source_file_data(in_file_name,lock):
     lock.acquire()     
     "written some code to write data from 'in_file_name' to a single target csv"
     lock.release()


if __name__ == "__main__":

    file_name_1 = sys.argv[1]
    file_name_2 = sys.argv[2]
    lock1 =multiprocessing.Lock()
    lock2 =multiprocessing.Lock()


    p1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=process_source_file_data, args=(file_name_1,lock1))
    p2 = multiprocessing.Process(target=process_source_file_data, args=(file_name_2,lock2))


    p1.start()
    p2.start()



    p1.join()
    p2.join()
```

Comment: When you run the program without multithreading, do you get the same breaks or not?

Comment: Then I wont, but the performance is very poor than

Comment: If you don't get the same breaks with a single thread, then it is probably has something to do with how the results are joined in the end.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a lock for each resource you are sharing between processes, as oppose to the lock for each process in your example.

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Lock

def f(i, l):
    l.acquire()
    try:
        print('hello world', i)
        print('hello world', i)
    finally:
        l.release()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    lock = Lock()

    for num in range(10):
        Process(target=f, args=(num, lock)).start()

RESULT:
hello world 1
hello world 1
hello world 4
hello world 0
hello world 4
hello world 2
hello world 0
hello world 2
hello world 3
hello world 3
hello world 5
hello world 5
hello world 7
hello world 7
hello world 6
hello world 6
hello world 9
hello world 9
hello world 8
hello world 8
```

Using a lock for each process will not allow the lock acquisition information to be transferred between processes:

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Lock

def f(i, l):
    l.acquire()
    try:
        print('hello world', i)
        print('hello world', i)
    finally:
        l.release()

if __name__ == '__main__':

    for num in range(10):
        lock = Lock()
        Process(target=f, args=(num, lock)).start()
```

This will result in that:

```
hello world 5
hello world 2
hello world 2
hello world 5
hello world 1
hello world 1
hello world 0
hello world 0
hello world 4
hello world 4
hello world 3
hello world 3
hello world 6
hello world 6
hello world 7
hello world 7
hello world 8
hello world 8
hello world 9
hello world 9
```

Comment: If I use same lock in each process, then it is same as running python script without using multiprocessing. Each process has to wait util previous lock is released

Comment: Yes but then you can make the calculation in parallel. When you use a lock for a whole process you don't really "lock" the file since the other process can still access it and write in. Why not saving the data from the input file to a variable and write to the file only once in a while?